# Every other icon in ListView not showing up

Tags: java, android, listview, icons

I have a List with a custom ArrayAdapter that loads icons next to the list items except only every other list item is showing an icon

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filetypeslist, parent, false);
        String[] items = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filetypes);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvtype);

        tv.setText(items[position]);

        if(items[position].equals("txt")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.txticon);//not showing up
        }else if(items[position].equals("HTML")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.htmlicon);
        }else if(items[position].equals("JS")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.javascripticon);//not showing up
        }else if(items[position].equals("CSS")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.cssicon);
        }

        return row;
    }
```

}

```
public class NewFile extends ListActivity {
    EditTextLineNumbers newet;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_file);
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.tvtype, 
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filetypes)));
    }


}

***EDIT***
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filetypeslist, parent, false);
        }
        String[] items = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filetypes);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvtype);

        tv.setText(items[position]);

        if(items[position].equals("txt")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.txticon);
        }else if(items[position].equals("HTML")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.htmlicon);
        }else if(items[position].equals("JS")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.javascripticon);
        }else if(items[position].equals("PHP")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.phpicon);
        }else if(items[position].equals("CSS")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.cssicon);
        }

        return row;
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <string-array name="filetypes">
        <item name="txt">Text</item>
        <item name="html">HTML</item>
        <item name="js">Javascript Class</item>
        <item name="css">CSS</item>
        <item name="php">PHP Class</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Are you sure the correctness about the StringArray "array.filetypes", would you please show me the resource file about the arrays.xml

Comment: Just as Karakuri pointed out that, try to correct this and if there is any question, you can comment it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chain of `String.equals` comparisons is not checking for the correct values for the two that aren't showing up. You are checking for "JS" instead of "Javascript class" and "txt" instead of "Text".

Aside from that, I have a few suggestions:

1. With ArrayAdapter, you can get the string for the current row by calling `getItem(position)` instead.
2. Make an `int-array` in your resources and have each item point to a drawable corresponding to the item in your `string-array`.
3. Let your adapter store local copies of those arrays instead of constructing them from resources every time `getView` is called. Same for the `LayoutInflater` (build these in the constructor of the adapter). Then you can get the drawable id as `intArray[position]` instead of a chain of `String.equals()` comparisons.
4. Use the convertView whenever possible as Shoshi pointed out.

Comment: Thanks! I was using the name property. Oops. Thanks for the other tips too.

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View row = convertView;
if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filetypeslist, parent, false);
}

...............
...............
}
```

Comment: in my code i have used `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);` so try by changing `row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filetypeslist, parent, false);`

Comment: i have also used 3 parameter constructor of adapter, like `public ActionListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, String[] strings) {
            super(context, resourceId, strings);` . i have not use something like u used `int textViewResourceId` parameter

Comment: i have used my own list layout rather than the default like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`